# touch & gzip all HTML, CSS, JS files in a directory recursively

Tags: find, nginx, gzip

I'm trying to optimize Nginx server. I've enabled Gzip_Static_Module to serve pre-compressed gzip static files like CSS, JS, HTML.

Nginx Wiki says that the timestamps of the compressed and uncompressed files match. So, I'm trying to touch the files before Gzipping.

I'm trying to touch and generate `*.gz` for these static files using the commands below:

```
$ su -c "find . -type f -name "*.css" -size +1024b -exec sh -c "touch {} \
    && gzip -9v < {} > {}.gz" \;"

$ su -c "find . -type f -name "*.js" -size +1024b -exec sh -c "touch {} \
    && gzip -9v < {} > {}.gz" \;"

$ su -c "find . -type f -name "*.html" -size +1024b -exec sh -c "touch {} \
    && gzip -9v < {} > {}.gz" \;"
```

but I receive "User {} not found" error.

Can anyone please help me what's wrong in the above command? And is there any better approach for generating *.gz automatically, whenever the timestamp of any uncompressed file changes (Cronjob may be)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're running into a quoting issue because you've got double quotes contained inside the command you're trying to get `su -c ...` to execute. You might want to try wrapping the whole thing inside single quotes instead.

```
$ su -c 'find . -type f -name "*.css" -size +1024b -exec sh -c "touch {} && \
    gzip -9v < {} > {}.gz" \;'
```

You can also escape these contained double quotes but this often can become messy to debug so I'd avoid that, but depending on your style/taste preferences is another option as well.

Comment: or putting all the commands into a script that is executed via 'sudo new-script'.  Sure it is not a one-liner, but it will save you from all the layered quoting issues. (sudo is far perferred over su)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to "touch" the file before calling `gzip`?

From `gzip`'s man page:

> Gzip  reduces the size of the named files using Lempel-Ziv coding
>   (LZ77). Whenever possible, each file is replaced by one with the
>   extension .gz, while keeping the same ownership modes, access and
>   modification times.

You don't have to touch the file at all, simply run:

`$ su -c "find . -type f -name \"*.css\" -size +1024b -exec gzip -9vk '{}' \;`

I've used the `-k` option of `gzip` which will keep the original file around after compression. This option has been introduced in version 1.6 of `gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way:

```
DIR=/var/www
gzip -rk9 $DIR &&\
find $DIR -not -name '*.gz' -type f -exec touch -r {} {}.gz \;
```

This gzips everything (at the 'best' level) in your www dir, then uses touch to set the mtime & atime of the gzip to that of the corresponding source file (as the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html#gzip_static) suggest).

Answer (score -1):

My version is:

`IFS=$'\0' find $DIR -type f -iname \*.html -or -iname \*.css -or -iname \*.js | while read fn; do gzip -9vk -- "$fn" && touch -r "$fn" "${fn}.gz"; done`

### Update

gzip actually keeps mod time needed by nginx to check if *content is the same*, so a simpler one liner is sufficient:

`find public/ -type f -iname \*.html -or -iname \*.css -or -iname \*.js -or -iname \*.xml -print0 | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty --verbose gzip -9vk --`

Answer (score -1):

```
find dist -type f -exec sh -c "gzip < '{}' > '{}'.gz" \;
```